# Android app in OPEN TEST - Access Denied for all users

Tags: android, access-denied, opentest

I Promoted a new Google app to OPEN TEST. The users can install but the access is blocked ("Lack of Google Verification Process").

Based on the instructions the verification process is only required when the app goes to production, which is not the case.
In the "Open Test->Testers" tab there are two available links:

- One for installation via ANDROID
- The second for installation via WEB

Using the Android link the users are able to download and install the app, however after passing the log in page they receive a message: "Error 403 Access Denied" and a text saying that the app has not completed the validation process and can only be used by users approved by the developer, which is not the case in OPEN TESTS.

I noticed that by using the WEB link (which is different) in a desktop browser the behavior is not the same. In this case the user passes through extra agreements and then he/she is authorized to download the app. Unfortunately we cannot use this option, because we need the downloads directly in the phone.

Did anybody experience something like that?

Thank you in advance.

We distributed the link to several users in locations assigned to the open tests.
We also tried to distribute the link provided in the WEB option for the same users.
In both cases the users are redirected to the play store where a early access version of the app is available. The users download and install it successfully, but cannot login.

We expected what is explained in the OPEN TEST instruction. That any approved device in the regions we defied are able to log in and test the application.